How do I bind to a value in an @Observable view model without invalidating all views in SwiftUI?
Migrating your view models from the @ObservedObject protocol to the @Observable macro should reduce the amount of ceremony in your view models (e.g., @Published property wrappers) while increasing the performance of your app as the @Observable macro promises to more intelligent only invalidate the views that need an update. However, when I bind to a string value in an @Observable view model, the opposite seems to happen:

Binding directly to the string value in the ViewModel through $viewModel.text causes all views to be invalided, even the ones that do not depend on the text value.
Trying to create a @Bindable reference to the viewModel as per the docs gives a compiler error.
Introducing subviews that allow for a @Bindable view model work (in the sense that now only the views that depend on the text value get invalidated), but does not seem like a sustainable approach as we now have a lot of ceremony again - be it in the form of unnecessary subviews rather than e.g., @Published property wrappers.

Below is a simple app demonstrating the issues. When running this on a simulator the let _ = Self._printChanges() calls will show which views get invalided when in the logs.
I’m using Xcode 15.4 and targeting iOS 17+.

import SwiftUI

// MARK: - ContentView
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        let _ = Self._printChanges()
        NavigationStack {
            UserListView()
                .navigationTitle("View Invalidations...")
        }
    }
}

// MARK: - Model

@Observable
class User: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    
}

// MARK: - Mock
extension User {
    static func random() -> User {
        return .init()
    }
    static func randomLot() -> [User] {
        var result: [User] = .init()
        for _ in 1..<50 {
            result.append(.random())
        }
        return result
    }
}


// MARK: - UserListView
struct UserListView: View {
    // ✅ Use @State because this view is the source of truth for this view model.
    @State var viewModel = ViewModel()
    // ❌ Direclty initialize a Bindable -> all views in list still get invalidated when using textfield.
//    @Bindable private var viewModel: ViewModel = .init()
    var body: some View {
        let _ = Self._printChanges()
        List {
            ForEach(viewModel.items) {
                UserRowView(item: $0)
            }
        }
        // ❌ Bind directly to property of viewmodel -> all views in list get invalidated when using textfield.
        .overlay(alignment: .bottom) {
            SomeCustomTextView(text: $viewModel.text)
        }
        // ❌ create @Bindable in view -> compiler error
//        .overlay(alignment: .bottom) {
//            VStack {
//                @Bindable var model = viewModel
//                SomeCustomTextView(text: $model.text)
//
//            }
//        }
        // ✅ create @bindable in another view
//        .overlay(alignment: .bottom) {
//            SomeOverLayView(viewModel: viewModel)
//        }

    }
}

// MARK: UserListView - ViewModel

extension UserListView {
    @Observable class ViewModel {
        var items: [User] = User.randomLot()
        var text: String = ""
        
    }
}

// MARK: - SomeCustomTextView

struct SomeCustomTextView: View {
    @Binding var text: String
    var body: some View {
        let _ = Self._printChanges()
        TextField("Can we type without invalidating all rows?", text: $text)
            .padding()
            .background(.regularMaterial, in: RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25.0))
            .padding()
            .shadow(radius: 20)
    }
}

// MARK: - UserRowView

struct UserRowView: View {
    @State private var viewModel: ViewModel
    init(item: User) {
        _viewModel = .init(wrappedValue: .init(item: item))
    }
    var body: some View {
        let _ = Self._printChanges()
        Text(viewModel.user.id.uuidString)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
        
    }
}
// MARK: UserRowView - ViewModel

extension UserRowView {
    @Observable class ViewModel {
        var user: User
        init(item: User) {
            self.user = item
        }
   
    }
}


//  MARK: - Alternative, but not ideal solutions

// ✅ If we create a @Bindable of the viewmodel, we can type text without invalidating the rows...
// FIXME:  But this approach woudld introduce a lot of overhead in production applications.
struct SomeOverLayView: View {
    var viewModel: UserListView.ViewModel
    var body: some View {
        let _ = Self._printChanges()
        @Bindable var model = viewModel
        SomeCustomTextView(text: $model.text)

    }
}

// ✅ Another approach would be to let the view take the viewmodel as a dependency.
// FIXME: but this again introduces a lot of overhead.
struct SomeCustomTextViewV2: View {
    @Bindable var viewModel: UserListView.ViewModel
    var body: some View {
        let _ = Self._printChanges()
        TextField("test", text: $viewModel.text)
    }
}


#Preview {
    ContentView()
}

edit 1: having view models share dependencies seems to be part of the problem; changing the UserRowView to not use a view model but directly depend on the user instead also solves the issue.
struct UserRowView: View {
    var item: User
    var body: some View {
        let _ = Self._printChanges()
        Text(item.id.uuidString)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
        
    }
}

Yet in more complex projects we might want to have view models with shared dependencies? And that we can solve the problem by introducing subviews and keeping the user row view models seems to indicate we should be able to...
edit 2
Creating the @Bindable directly below the view's body compiles, but does not solve the view invalidation issue:
struct UserListView: View {
    @State var viewModel = ViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        let _ = Self._printChanges()
        // ❌ Creating the bindable here compiles, but still results in manny unnecessary view invalidations when the viewModel's text value changes.
        @Bindable var viewModel = viewModel
        List {
            ForEach(viewModel.items) {
                UserRowView(item: $0)
            }
        }
        .overlay(alignment: .bottom) {
            // ❌ although technically still within the view's body, adding the @Bindable here gives compiler errors.
            // @Bindable var viewModel = viewModel
            SomeCustomTextView(text: $viewModel.text)
        }
        // ✅ create @bindable in another view
        //        .overlay(alignment: .bottom) {
        //            SomeOverLayView(viewModel: viewModel)
        //        }
    }
}


In SwiftUI the View structs are the view model already and it automatically generates the actual view depending on the platform. You shouldn’t try to use your own view model objects. You need a model store singleton to store your model Observable objects, State is just for view data structs or values.

Is your ViewModel also a @Observable class ViewModel? Can you show the code for it?
Try moving the @Bindable var viewModel = viewModel inside the body of the View. Note that
using @Bindable private var viewModel: ViewModel = .init() is useless, this binds to a different model than your
@State var viewModel = ViewModel(). See also Managing data

@workingdogsupportUkraine moving the @Bindable viewModel = viewModel from the .overlay{} to directly below the view's body compiles, but still leads to many unnecessary view invalidations when the text value changes.
I am indeed also using @Observable for the view model class. All code is provided. Specifically the view model is implemented as an extension on the view (see the code).

Try this approach using @Bindable var viewModel = viewModel in UserListView and let item: User in your UserRowView,
as shown in this code:
// MARK: - ContentView
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        let _ = Self._printChanges()
        NavigationStack {
            UserListView()
                .navigationTitle("View Invalidations...")
        }
    }
}

// MARK: - Model
@Observable
class User: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
}

// MARK: - Mock
extension User {
    static func random() -> User {
        return .init()
    }
    static func randomLot() -> [User] {
        var result: [User] = .init()
        for _ in 1..<50 {
            result.append(.random())
        }
        return result
    }
}

// MARK: - UserListView
struct UserListView: View {
    // ✅ Use @State because this view is the source of truth for this view model.
    @State private var viewModel = ViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        @Bindable var viewModel = viewModel  // <--- here
        let _ = Self._printChanges()
        List {
            ForEach(viewModel.items) {
                UserRowView(item: $0)
            }
        }
        .overlay(alignment: .bottom) {
            SomeCustomTextView(text: $viewModel.text)
        }
    }
}

// MARK: ViewModel, outside the View struct // <--- here
@Observable class ViewModel {
    var items: [User] = User.randomLot()
    var text: String = ""
}

// MARK: - SomeCustomTextView
struct SomeCustomTextView: View {
    @Binding var text: String
    
    var body: some View {
        let _ = Self._printChanges()
        TextField("Can we type without invalidating all rows?", text: $text)
            .padding()
            .background(.regularMaterial, in: RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25.0))
            .padding()
            .shadow(radius: 20)
    }
}

// MARK: - UserRowView
struct UserRowView: View {
    let item: User  // <--- here
    
    var body: some View {
        let _ = Self._printChanges()
        Text(item.id.uuidString)  // <--- here
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
    }
}

EDIT-1:
Even if you use a separate viewModel for the UserRowView as per your original code,
the code works well for me, ie that does not invalidate all views in SwiftUI.
 struct UserRowView: View {
     @State private var viewModel: RowViewModel
     
     init(item: User) {
         self._viewModel = .init(wrappedValue: .init(item: item))
       }
     
     var body: some View {
         let _ = Self._printChanges()
         Text(viewModel.user.id.uuidString)
             .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
         
     }
 }

 extension UserRowView {
     @Observable class RowViewModel {
         var user: User
         init(item: User) {
             self.user = item
         }
     }
 }


The @Bindable you introduce now is redundant, because as I already point out in my post indeed removing the view model from the user row view solves the view invalidation issues. However, as pointed out as well, this does not seem like a sustainable approach because for more complex projects you want to use separate view models for child views.

updated my answer (EDIT-1) adding a viewModel to the UserRowView child view.

If I use the separate viewmodel for the user row view, unfortunately it does again invalidate all rows when using the textfield... To be sure I copy pasted your code.
Are you sure that with the separate view model for the user row view you are only getting a single row invalidated when you type a character in the textfield?  If so, I'm starting to wonder if we have the same Swift/Xcode version (version 15.4 (15F31d)) or whether there can be some other culprit causing the deprecancy between what we are seeing.
